Ktor GET request with multipart body
I'm trying to make a GET request that has a multipart body in Ktor. However I get a server error 500 when I'm doing the following code:
client.get {
        url { path("the", "path") }
        setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(
            formData {
                append("clientId", clientId)
                append("code", code)
            }
        ))
}.body<Response>()

If I leave the body out, the server response with a missing body error.
If I do the same call in curl, it succeeds:
curl -X GET 'https://server.url/api/v1/the/path' \
  -d 'code=code' \
  -d 'clientId=clientId'

It is a third party server where I don't have any control, therefore I have to make a GET request with a data body. When I log the call I can see that indeed there is a body sent to the server:
HttpClient: REQUEST: https://server.url/api/v1/the/path
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=GET)
COMMON HEADERS
-> Accept: application/json
-> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
CONTENT HEADERS
-> Content-Length: 372
-> Content-Type: multipart/form-data;     boundary=69e936b8-4a7c7093-16bba07f-19d814e2708194c1-3248703532ce82f9-57eea5437
BODY Content-Type: multipart/form-data;     boundary=69e936b8-4a7c7093-16bba07f-19d814e2708194c1-3248703532ce82f9-57eea5437
BODY START
--69e936b8-4a7c7093-16bba07f-19d814e2708194c1-3248703532ce82f9-57eea5437
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=clientId
Content-Length: 8

clientId
--69e936b8-4a7c7093-16bba07f-19d814e2708194c1-3248703532ce82f9-57eea5437
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=code
Content-Length: 4

code
--69e936b8-4a7c7093-16bba07f-19d814e2708194c1-3248703532ce82f9-57eea5437--

BODY END

Why is it failing with my Ktor call, but succeeds when doing it in curl?

Can you see exactly what it is sending to the server? Including the headers? If possible get server logs or run the whole thing through some kind of proxy where you can log everything that is sent to the server. Do you know what the cause of the HTTP 500 is? The server logs should tell you.

Also, have you tried just adding the parameters to the URL query string instead of trying to send them in the body? This whole thing seems super strange.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the server logs and sending the body as query parameters does also not work.

Hard to believe. Can you update your post and show the code you use to add them as query parameters? Can you run everything through a proxy and log what is sent/received?

@DavidWasser you are right, adding them as query parameters is also accepted by the server and works. If you add it as answer I will accept it as solution.

If you are using GET, you should be able to add the parameters code and clientId as query parameters in the URL, instead of sending these in the body. The server should accept that.
